# Import CSV file in VBA but cannot preserve foreign symbols

Tags: excel, csv, unicode, import, symbols

I'm trying to create a script where I push a button and you get a pop-up window where you select your .CSV file and then loads it to a specific destination. So far have I managed to do what I just said but as a non-english user the data in my .CSV is written in Swedish and I need to have our "special" symbols preserved.

I've tried to record myself loading the file using the Import Data - wizard but I cannot wrap my head around that code in order to make it work with variable name/filepath.

What I've got so far is the code below, it loads the file quick and painless but do not preserve the special symbols like "åäö".

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Input")
ws.UsedRange.Clear
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")


With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, _
Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .Refresh
End With
```

The .CSV-file origin according to the import wizard is "65001: Unicode (UTF-8)" and I've tried to find properties for .QueryTables in order to recognize this.

One of many things I've tried is:

```
.QueryType = xlOLEDBQuery / xlTextImport
.TextFilePlatform = xlWindows / xlMSDOS
```

but the .QueryType only gives me either an "object doesn't support this method or property" or "invalid property assignment".

It feels like the problem lies with Excel not knowing how it should treat the coding of the file (the Unicode (UTF-8)) but I'm quite novice in this area so I might be looking at the wrong things.

Comment: In your connection string add something like `Encoding=65001`.  Or, if you have Office 365, you can record a macro while using the new Data Import Wizard and, on the first screen, you'll see a language option.

Comment: Thanks! This did lead me in the right direction! Since Im using Office 365 I will run the _new_ Data Import Wizard, which didn't give me much insight but enabling the Legacy Data Import in Options I got it. Recorded my actions and still alot of code but this time I found this:
.TextFilePlatform = 65001, which solved my problem!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ron Rosenfeld who led me in the right direction I found a solution to this.

All that was needed was:

```
.TextFilePlatform = 65001
```

I did enable the *Legacy* Data Import for Text in File > Options > Data.
Then I recorded my action while importing, within this code I found the line above which solved my problem.
Final code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Input")
ws.UsedRange.Clear
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, _
Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .Refresh
End With
```